# python call exec() inside a function

Tags: python

I try to execute string code using exec function which is being called at another function. However, it doesn't print anything. How do I execute string code in this case?

```
def test_code():
    print "test_code"

def run():
    try:
        a= '''def test2():
            print "test2"

            test_code()
            test2()'''

        exec(a)
    except Exception as e:
        print e

run()
```

Comment: You never _call_ `test2`. The `test_code()` and `test2()` calls are part of `test2`'s function body, because they're indented.

Answer (score 1):

You have a code indentation issue. try this:

```
def test_code():
    print "test_code"


def run():
    try:
        a= '''
def test2():
    print "test2"

test_code()
test2()
'''

        exec(a)
    except Exception as e:
        print e

run()
# test_code
# test2
```

Answer (score 0):

All problem is indentation of quoted string
Here is solution,

```
def test_code():
    print "test_code"

def run():
    try:
        a= '''
def test2():
    print "test2"
    test_code()
test2()'''

        exec(a)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
run()
```

Output

> test2
>
> test_code